# How to parse excel data into dataframe with particular format?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have an excel like this, in the 'Elements' sheet of the excel like below: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pT0PY.png

```
Item              Category  Value
TRANSPORT         A         1
Bus               A         2
Car               A         3
Automobile        A         4
Bike              A         5
ACCOMODATION      A         6
House             A         7
Apartment         A         8
DELIVERY          B         9
Glovo             B         10
Emag              B         11
Transporter       B         12
ACCOMODATION      B         13
Apartment1        B         14
Apartment2        B         15
ACCOMODATION      C         16
Rental            C         17
Apartment         C         18
```

I want to separate the items(TRANSPORT, ACCOMODATION, DELIVERY) from the elements(Bus, Car, Automobile, Bike...) into a dataframe like below:

```
      Element          Item Category  Value
0         Bus     TRANSPORT        A      2
1         Car     TRANSPORT        A      3
2  Automobile     TRANSPORT        A      4
3        Bike     TRANSPORT        A      5
4       House  ACCOMODATION        A      7
5   Apartment  ACCOMODATION        A      8
```

I have managed to write the code to separate the elements from the category A, but somehow the code breaks when I use it for the category B or C or others. It triggers:`IndexError: index 8 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 7` because of the trimming of indexes in the code. I need to extract the values for the Value column only for the elements, not for the items and it breaks because of the length mismatch.
I would need the final dataframe to contain all the information for all the categories from the Excel, not just for one category.
What I tried so far (working for category A only):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel('elements.xlsx',
                   ['Elements'], engine='openpyxl')

category_names = df['Elements']['Category'].unique()

df['Elements'] = df['Elements'].groupby(['Category'])

categ_group = ['TRANSPORT', 'ACCOMODATION', 'DELIVERY']


def create_category_df(category_name='A'):
    helper_df = df['Elements'].get_group(category_name)

    # get index for items
    item_index = helper_df[helper_df["Item"].isin(categ_group)].index.to_list()

    # get elements and associated items
    item_data = np.split(helper_df['Item'].to_numpy(), item_index)

    helper_df = helper_df.drop(helper_df.index[item_index])  # drop rows for items

    helper_df = helper_df.reset_index(drop=True)

    resulted_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Element', 'Item', 'Category', 'Value'])

    item_list = []
    for index in range(len(item_data)):
        if item_data[index].size != 0:
            resulted_df = resulted_df.append(pd.DataFrame(item_data[index][1:], columns=['Element']))
            item_list += len(item_data[index][1:]) * [
                item_data[index][0]]  # multiply items by number of times it is present and add it to df

    resulted_df['Category'] = category_name  # 'Hardware EA'
    resulted_df['Item'] = item_list
    resulted_df['Value'] = helper_df['Value'].values
    resulted_df = resulted_df.reset_index(drop=True)
    print(resulted_df.to_string())
    return resulted_df


create_category_df()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First replace columns names, then repalce non matched values of list by `NaN`s in [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html), so possible forward filling missing values in [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) for second new column and last remove rows if equal values in both columns in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
categ_group = ['TRANSPORT', 'ACCOMODATION', 'DELIVERY']

df = df.rename(columns={'Item':'Element'})
df.insert(1, 'Item', df['Element'].where(df['Element'].isin(categ_group)).ffill())
df =df[ df['Element'].ne(df['Item'])]

print (df)
        Element          Item Category  Value
1           Bus     TRANSPORT        A      2
2           Car     TRANSPORT        A      3
3    Automobile     TRANSPORT        A      4
4          Bike     TRANSPORT        A      5
6         House  ACCOMODATION        A      7
7     Apartment  ACCOMODATION        A      8
9         Glovo      DELIVERY        B     10
10         Emag      DELIVERY        B     11
11  Transporter      DELIVERY        B     12
13   Apartment1  ACCOMODATION        B     14
14   Apartment2  ACCOMODATION        B     15
16       Rental  ACCOMODATION        C     17
17    Apartment  ACCOMODATION        C     18
```